# Error: Map theme file does not exist... (Qt5 application with third party libraries Marble)

Tags: qt, ubuntu, marble

I am trying to deploy a Qt5 application with a Marble plugin using dynamic linking. I have put the Qt5 libs, platform plugins and the marble libmarblewidget-qt5.so.22 with my executable application. The application works from an Ubuntu with marble installed on it. Now I am trying to run the application on an Ubuntu without marble installed. I am using the startup script from  http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux-deployment.html to start my application. I am working on Ubuntu 16.04 32-bits.

When I run the startup script for the application (from terminal) I get this error message:

```
Map theme file does not exist: ""
Ignoring to load the following file since it doesn't look like a valid Marble plugin: "/boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-21-generic" 
Reason: "'/boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-21-generic' is not an ELF object"
Ignoring to load the following file since it doesn't look like a valid Marble plugin: "/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-21-generic" 
Reason: "'/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-21-generic' is not an ELF object"
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Am I missing something, should I have something more than just the libmarblewidget-qt5.so.22?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marble needs more than `libmarblewidget-qt5.so` to run properly. At least you need data for the map theme you want to show, and usually also some plugins. Have a look at the installation folder (`CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`) after compiling Marble. You'll find plugins in e.g. `lib64/marble/` and data in `share/marble/data`.

The paths to plugins and data is compiled into `libmarblewidget-qt5.so`, but can be changed at runtime. To do so, use `MarbleDirs::setMarbleDataPath()` and `MarbleDirs::setMarblePluginPath()`.

In short, you have to

- ship all or some plugins to a folder of your choice
- Call `MarbleDirs::setMarblePluginPath("/your/plugins/install/folder");`
- ship all or some data to another folder of your choice
- Call `MarbleDirs::setMarbleDataPath("/your/data/install/folder");`

The output you get (and likely also the segfault) happens because the compiled in plugin path does not exist on the target system, therefore Marble's plugin manager searches in `/` and tries to load the files it finds there.

Comment: Thanks, the application runs well now.